# Export HTML datatable to Excel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, excel, datatable, datatables

I have used https://www.datatables.net example
Following is my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {var data = <%=liveProjectData %>
                 $("#empdetails").html('<table  id="example" class="table-responsive table-bordered table-hover" ></table>');
            $("#example").dataTable({
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                         "aButtons": ["xls", "pdf", "print"]
                },
                "columns": [{
                    "title": "A"
                }, {
                    "title": "B"
                }, {
                    "title": "C"
                }, {
                    "title": "D"
                }, {
                    "title": "E"
                }
                ],
                "data": function () {
                    return $.map(data, function (attribute) {
                        return [
                            ["<div class='badge badge-" + attribute.A + "'>" + attribute.A + "</div>", attribute.B, attribute.C, attribute.D, attribute.E, '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconcls="icon-ok" onclick="EditProjectDetails(' + attribute.A + ')">EDIT</a>'] ] })}()}) }); function EditProjectDetails(A) { window.location = "viewClientDetailToAdmin.aspx?A=" + A };
```

and I have binded data to the following div

```
<div class="row">  <div class="col-md-12" id="empdetails"></div></div>
```

I read about datatable tool at https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/
which exports HTML table data to pdf, excel

Please help me to download in Excel whatever in HTML table I have binded.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to achieve it:

1. The data is exported in CSV format which can be opened using Excel
2. You can do ajax query, generate xlsx format file and render it using a popup or redirect
3. You can write flash/actionscript to generate XLSX files in browser but that's bit cumbersome [For reading xlsx file, you can use this though: https://github.com/childoftv/as3-xlsx-reader]

EDIT: You can also look at https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js